# Laravel With and wherePivot

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot

I'm trying to extract all companies and contacts with pivot.main_contact = 1.

Tables:

```
Company: id, name
Company_contacts: id, company_id, contact_id, main_contact
Contacts: id, name
```

Model:

```
class Company extends Model
{
        public function mainContact()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contact', 'company_contacts')
                        ->wherePivot('main_contact', '=', 1);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
$query = Company::with('mainContact')->get();
```

This returns companies + ALL contacts for the companies and NOT ONLY the ones with main_contact = 1.

Comment: Could you check your mysql query log and copy the raw SQL query into your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, for reasons I'm unsure of, you need to add `withPivot('main_contact');` to your relation. This will return `main_contact` in your collection under `pivot`

```
class Company extends Model
{
        public function mainContact()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contact', 'company_contacts')
                        ->withPivot('main_contact');
    }
}
```

The second thing you need to do is use `withPivot()` while [constraint eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) like so:

```
$companies = Company::with(['mainContact'=> function($query){
    $query->wherePivot('main_contact', 1);
}])->get();
```

I've checked it, it works.

Just to go a bit above and beyond. Sometimes you'll want to query a pivot table without knowing the value. You can do so by:

```
$companies = Company::with(['mainContact'=> function($query) use ($contact){
    $query->wherePivot('main_contact', $contact);
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add [`withPivot()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contact', 'company_contacts')
    ->withPivot('main_contact')
    ->wherePivot('main_contact', '=', 1);
```

Comment: Tried that. It returnt the same result. It is just like when using with everything behing belongsToMany is ignored even; ->orderBy

Answer (score 0):

`Company::with('mainContact')->get();` returns all compaines and all contacts. You should be doing `$company->mainContacts()->get();` instead.

```
$companies=Company::all();
foreach($companies as $company)
{
   print_r($company->mainContact()->get());
}
die;
```

Comment: This will create N+1 number of queries (i.e. 10001 queries for table with 10000 rows) instead of just 2. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin with eager loading `$query->mainContact` gives the companies with  main_contact 1.

Comment: Rather just do two queries if possible. (there are a few more relationships to  load actually.

Comment: @Line in Linus `foreach($query as $q){ $q->minContact;}` will give only the companies with  min_contact value 1.